# Original documents for UK visa biometric appointment

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I'm a Sri Lankan citizen, currently in Serbia, and I'm planning to apply for a UK visa. I have secured an appointment to provide my fingerprints and passport at the UK Visa application center here in Belgrade.

I have a question about the papers I'm supposed to submit.

My bank is in Sri Lanka, and I could get them to send me scanned copies of signed and stamped statements of my bank account. I have an invitation letter in PDF form. It would cost me some.money and time to get these documents in an Express courier service.

When making the appointment, I chose the option to upload the documents online myself (as opposed to assisted scanning at the visa application center). My question is, whether do I need to submit the original physical documents at the visa center. If they are going to scan the documents and upload them anyway, I might as well upload the papers.

In a UK visa application, if I upload the documents myself, would I need to submit the original papers for the visa officers to inspect?

Comment: Better confirm with the UK Visa application center. Third parties are always here and there with their understanding of the rules(from own experience). So it will save you lot of grief if you ask them to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need to take the original documents to the application center. That would defeat the purpose of “self-upload.” When you complete your application online it does say you will need to bring original passports even if you have uploaded them yourself. That implies if you have self-uploaded documents ONLY passports needed to be bought.

Answer (score 0):

The Guide to supporting documents states “All documents must be originals and not photocopies” https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk

You could submit a photocopy of your bank statements only if the copy itself bears an original stamp by the bank on each page. A photocopy that included a copy stamp would not be acceptable, IMHO.

Comment: That’s not true. You are now allowed to self-upload documents. You don’t even have to bring copies to the application center. All you need to bring is your passport and confirmation letter.